# Retrieve notifications with JavaScript

Tags: 2013, javascript, client-object-model, social

I want to incorporate social feed into my SharePoint webpart. I followed this tutorial: [Code example: Retrieve social feeds by using the SharePoint 2013 JavaScript object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj164025.aspx#bkmk_GetFeeds). 
Even if I used exactly the same JavaScript code, when I get to this line:

```
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(CallIterateFunctionForFeeds, RequestFailed);
```

the method always returns with an error:

```
The request was aborted: The request was canceled
```

My question:
Are there some settings in SharePoint, that I may need to change? Could I have missed something, that is not covered in the tutorial?

Oh, and my solution is deployed as Farm Solution.

Comment: Do you have Full Control on the User Profile Service Application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the problem was SqlException. My web application is different than MySites web app. Application pool user of my web app could not login to content database of MySites web app.